# python convert JSON object contet type

Tags: json, python-3.x, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm working on reading data stored in text and csv files using python and process them to create a new JSON document and all works fine except for the content type is `application/octet-stream` but when I create the JSON document I want this file content type to be `application/json`.

[image]

Data in `json_document` variable

```
[
   {
      "URL":"http://myexample.net",
      "domain":"abc",
      "domainSerialId":"skdksj12391ncjsacn",
      "proxy":"myexample.net"
   },
   {
      "URL":"http://myexample.org",
      "domain":"def",
      "domainSerialId":"sakdjsaye132978ejwdnwd",
      "proxy":"myexample.org"
   }
]

json.dumps(json_document)
```

This is the new consolidated JSON document that gets created. Having issue trying to convert the content type using `json.dumps`. I upload these documents to Azure blob storage and see the file `Content Type` to be different.

Comment: What content type? Where? Who determines it? What "issues" are you having?

Comment: @Yarin_007, When I upload json documents manually to azure blob storage I see the correct `Content Type` `application/json` and when I use python code to accomplish the same the content type is `application/octet-stream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the Blob Service API, you need to specify the `content_type` in your request, otherwise, the default is `application/octet-stream`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob

Here is a code example using the Azure Python SDK:

```
# Instantiate a BlobServiceClient using a connection string
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(self.connection_string)

# Instantiate a ContainerClient
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("mynewcontainer")

# Set mime-type and upload file
content_settings = ContentSettings(content_type='application/json')
container_client.upload_blob(name=dest_path, data=contents.encode('utf-8'),overwrite=True, content_settings=content_settings)
```

Comment: I'm using [azure.storage.blob BlobServiceClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclient?view=azure-python)

Comment: `ContentSettings` helps other than that the only change I made is `encoding='utf-8'`. Thank you